# Adding A File To An Attachment Column In An Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm using the following code:

```
Public Sub Add_File(Update_Table As Integer)

    Dim Fpath = My.Settings.Database_Connection_String



    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True
    fd.Multiselect = True


    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim FileRow
        Try
            FileRow = Form1.Projects_DGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex
        Catch ex As Exception
            FileRow = 0
        End Try

        Dim FileX = Form1.Projects_DGV.Item(0, FileRow).Value




        For Each file As String In fd.FileNames

            strFileName = file



            ' this code requires that your project have the following COM Reference:
            '     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library

            Dim dbe As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
            Dim db As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database = dbe.OpenDatabase(My.Settings.Database_Location)
            Dim rstRecord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset = db.OpenRecordset( _
                    "SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE [Project ID]=" & FileX, _
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
            rstRecord.Edit()
            Dim rstAttachments As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset2
            If Update_Table = 1 Then
                rstAttachments = rstRecord.Fields("Invoice").Value
            ElseIf Update_Table = 2 Then
                rstAttachments = rstRecord.Fields("Software Handover").Value
            ElseIf Update_Table = 3 Then
                rstAttachments = rstRecord.Fields("Other Documents").Value
            ElseIf Update_Table = 4 Then
                rstAttachments = rstRecord.Fields("Project Documents").Value
            End If



            rstAttachments.AddNew()
            Dim AttachmentData As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Field2 = rstAttachments.Fields("FileData")
            AttachmentData.LoadFromFile(strFileName)
            rstAttachments.Update()
            rstAttachments.Close()
            rstRecord.Update()
            rstRecord.Close()
            db.Close()

        Next
        setupdatagrids()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is supposed to allow me to add a file as an attachment to a database, and it works just fine in another 2 projects, but for some reason is not working now. The code fails on this line:

```
Dim rstRecord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset = db.OpenRecordset( _
                        "SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE [Project ID]=" & FileX, _
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
```

with the error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Alveare -
>   Complete Management Tool.exe
>
> Additional information: Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Anyone have any ideas why this would be, as I am passing a parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the value of `FileX` contains spaces and that is screwing up the execution of the SQL?

Comment: Should the value of `FileX` be quoted in the SQL anyway?  Unless it's a integer, it should.  I also notice that you must have `Option Strict Off` and that's never good.  It allows various issues to sneak through that might other wise be caught earlier.

Comment: ah, in all of the other projects the primary key of the database has always been an ID integer, however, in this database, it is a string "F002 - X" for example. What would I need to change to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `Project ID` column contains text rather than numbers, change this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE [Project ID]=" & FileX
```

to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE [Project ID]='" & FileX & "'"
```

or this:

```
String.Format("SELECT * FROM [Projects] WHERE [Project ID]='{0}'", FileX)
```

My preference would be the second option.

Comment: Thanks, I used your first option and it works a treat